# Plotting data with different x-axis on the same graph in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, visualization

I have one dataframe that looks a bit like this:

**df1**

| County | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dune | 0.20 | 0.33 | 0.28 | 0.56 |
| Clarke | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.30 | 0.63 |
| Adams | 0.19 | 0.30 | 0.30 | 0.59 |
| Burke | 0.23 | 0.29 | 0.29 | 0.54 |
| James | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.23 | 0.52 |

and another that looks like this:

**df2**

| Month | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.19 | 0.40 | 0.28 | 0.56 |
| 2 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.99 | 0.77 |
| 3 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.53 | 0.93 |
| 4 | 0.58 | 0.87 | nan | 0.62 |
| 5 | nan | 1.11 | 0.23 | 1.01 |
| 6 | nan | 0.67 | 0.55 | 0.83 |
| 7 | nan | 1.06 | 0.72 | 0.92 |
| 8 | nan | nan | 0.88 | 0.99 |
| 9 | nan | nan | 0.99 | 1.06 |
| 10 | nan | nan | nan | 1.16 |
| 11 | nan | nan | nan | 1.12 |

I would like to create a bar chart with the data from df1 with a line chart from df2 in the background. The x-axis would be time, from 2019-2022.
Is this possible? I've tried multiple iterations using matplotlib and seaborn but haven't landed on anything quite like I'm looking for.

Comment: What should be the X and Y values for df1 and df2?

Comment: I edited my question to specify. X should be time, Y should be the decimal values associated with each time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data, there is still some clarity required. But, made some assumptions on what you need.

As df1 has year AND county, assuming you are looking for grouped bar chart. Also, you have year and month for df2. Assuming you are looking for month-wise line plot. You do NOT want to see data where NaN is present (basically the line plot is not continuous).

While it is possible to do the bar plot with matplotlib, I am using seaborn for this, as it is just so much easier to do it.

Also, used matplotlib lineplot because they allow for discrete lines, meaning that if there is no value (NaN) for a particular cell, the line will stop and restart when the next value is available. Steps followed are below.

1. As the data has year as columns, we need to move them to rows. I have used `melt` for this
2. Added a column `df2.Period`, which has the format `Month-Year`
3. Using seaborn barplot for df1 and matplotlib lineplot for df2, I have created the two graphs.
4. As the X-axes are different, I am using `twiny()` so that the df1 axis values are the bottom of the plot and the df2 axis values are the top.

Please refer to below code and plot. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
## Change the data to the format that allows for easy plotting ##
df1=df1.melt(id_vars="County", var_name="Year", value_name="Value")
df2=df2.melt(id_vars="Month", var_name="Year", value_name="Value")
df2['Period']=df2["Month"].astype(str) + '-' + df2["Year"].astype(str)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))  ## Set figure size
ax1=sns.barplot(data=df1, x='Year', y='Value', hue='County') ## Create barplot

ax2=ax1.twiny() ## Tell python that lineplot axis is to be plotted on top

ax2.plot('Period', 'Value', data=df2, marker='.')#, ci=None) ## Create lineplot

ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=45) ## Rotate df2 x-axis labels
ax1.legend(loc='upper left') ## Move the legend
```

**Output plot**
[image]